# Destroy Game Object after a few seconds of activating child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code

```
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
    {
        if ( Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000f ) )
        {
            for(int i=0; i< hit.collider.transform.childCount; i++)
            {
                var child = hit.collider.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
                if(child != null)
                    child.SetActive(true);
            }
            hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;         

            //Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}
```

This code sits on my camera in my scene. What it does is allows me to touch a game object and destroy. The first object I touch is a 2D sprite and I've turn off its sprite renderer and turn on its childs, sprite renderer.

However, I need a way to destroy the game object once this is done. I'm truly at a loss as to how I can achieve this.

Comment: If you're gameobject implements the IDisposable interface, use the Dispose method

Comment: Do you just want to destroy the parent gameobject without destroying its childs? In this case if you set the GO renderer to false like this `hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.enabled = false;` must works.

Answer (score 0):

`Destroy (gameObject, 5);`will destroy in 5 seconds.

Also you can use in the OnMouseDown() and spare all the for loop and raycast stuff in update

If you do want the OnMouseDown() you would of course need the script on the object prefab and not the camera though.

Comment: So this is not the answer to this question? Then this should not be here ;)